# PouchDB get list of all databases with Typescript

Tags: typescript, pouchdb

I want to get the list of all databases of my local server of CouchDB. Using CouchDB API I can list the databases, but using PouchDB I don't find anywhere how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PouchDB does not support that natively, due to limitations in local storage--it doesn't allow a listing of existing content.  If you use the [pouchdb-all-dbs](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-all-dbs) plugin, it will emulate the functionality for you, by watching all databases as they are created or deleted. But you must use this plugin at all times, to expect an accurate list.